# Searching pages for more than one tag values

Tags: tags, aem

I am using CQ 5.6.1 and want to search pages that are tagged to more than one values of tags. For example: I want to search all the pages that are tagged to:

topicId=investment and language=english and type = something

I can do it for single value of tag like

```
    searchMap.put(tagid, topicId);
    searchMap.put(tagid.property, @jcr:content/cq:tags);
```

How can I implement it for more than one values of tags.

Thanks

Ankit

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many tagid's you want by specifying number prefixes like the one's shown below

```
searchMap.put("type", "cq:Page");
searchMap.put("1_tagid", topicId);
searchMap.put("1_tagid.property", "jcr:content/cq:tags");
searchMap.put("2_tagid", anothertopicId);
searchMap.put("2_tagid.property", "jcr:content/cq:tags");
```

The above query is similar to the following XPath query

```
//element(*, cq:Page) [
jcr:content/@cq:tags = 'marketing:interest/business' and jcr:content/@cq:tags = 'marketing:interest/product' 
]
```

For more details on queries, refer [this](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html)